# apache camel how to get header attributes from sql-component

Tags: apache-camel

I'm new to Apache Camel and I've stared to write an application that grabs data from one database and inserts it to another database. I'm using the sql component and am trying to figure out how to grab the CamelSqlUpdateCount, CamelSqlRowCount and CamelSqlQuery from the message header using spring dsl.

I know that I can get attributes in the data using this....

```
<log message="Processing product ${body[product_id]}"/>
```

But when I try to grab data from my header after my insert like this...

```
<from uri="sourceSql:{{sql.selectProduct}}"/>
<log message="SELECT,${header.CamelSqlQuery},${header.CamelSqlRowCount}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="db_log"/>
<to uri="targetSql:{{sql.insertProductOrig}}"/>     
<log message="INSERT,CONV_ORIG,${header.CamelSqlQuery},${header.CamelSqlUpdateCount}" loggingLevel="INFO" logName="db_log"/>
```

it comes back empty. After getting advice on turning on a trace in my route to see what is coming back in the message headers I can see that those header attributes are not there. I am connecting to sql server to select and mysql to insert. does anyone know what might be wrong?

I've attached some sample output from the trace...

```
2013-09-04,21:11:55.615,MacBook-local >>> (processProduct-route) from(sourceSql://SELECT%20TOP%205%20product_id%20FROM%20product_) --> log[SELECT,${header.CamelSqlQuery},${header.CamelSqlRowCount}] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=MacBook-local}, BodyType:org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap, Body:{product_id=273}
    2013-09-04,21:11:55.625,MacBook-local >>> (processProduct-route) log[SELECT,${header.CamelSqlQuery},${header.CamelSqlRowCount}] --> multicast <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=MacBook-local}, BodyType:org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap, Body:{product_id=273}
    2013-09-04,21:11:55.644,MacBook-local >>> (processProduct-route) from(sourceSql://SELECT%20TOP%205%20product_id%20FROM%20product_) --> targetSql://insert%20into%20conv_stg_product_%20(product_id)%20values%20(:%23product_id) <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=MacBook-local}, BodyType:org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap, Body:{product_id=273}
    2013-09-04,21:11:55.646,MacBook-local >>> (processProduct-route) from(sourceSql://SELECT%20TOP%205%20product_id%20FROM%20product_) --> log[INSERT,CONV_STG,${header.CamelSqlQuery},${header.CamelSqlUpdateCount}] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=MacBook}, BodyType:org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap, Body:{product_id=273}
    2013-09-04,21:11:55.642,MacBook >>> (processProduct-route) from(sourceSql://SELECT%20TOP%205%20product_id%20FROM%20product_) --> log[INSERT,CONV_ORIG,${header.CamelSqlQuery},${header.CamelSqlUpdateCount}] <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=MacBook}, BodyType:org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap, Body:{product_id=273}
```

Here are what the sql statements look like...

```
sql.selectProduct=SELECT TOP 5 product_id FROM product_
sql.insertProductOrig=insert into conv_orig_product_ (product_id) values (:#product_id)
```

Here is an extract from my POM to show what jdbc drivers I am  using...

```
<!-- SQL Server database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
    <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>  

<!-- MySQL database driver -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

thanks

Comment: What version of Camel do you use?

Comment: 2.11 - am I using correct syntax?

Comment: Yes the 1st syntax is correct. You can enable tracing and see the headers on the message: http://camel.apache.org/tracer. To see if its empty, or which headers is on the message.

Comment: Thanks that helped me to trace down what was in the headers. The only thing in the header is the breadcrumb id. Those header values documented on at http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html#SQLComponent-Headervalues do not appear in the trace. Not sure what is going on. I'll have to do more research to find out if anyone else had this issue.

Comment: Still can't figure this out. I've updated the post to give more information

Comment: What are you SQL queries. The update header is when you do an insert/update etc. And the row header is when you do a SELECT etc. So maybe you do something different.

Comment: Modified post to show sql queries

Comment: What database and JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: And does data gets inserted into the database? eg does the route work, but only the header is missing?

Comment: Hi Claus yes the inserts definitely work. I've modified the post to show my jdbc drivers. It's sql server for the select and mysql for the inserts

Comment: I was thinking. Perhaps a good work around for this would be to write a custom processor class which would log the size of the resultset? Does that sounds feasible? If so how would that look roughly?

Comment: I suspect it could be a bug in that release.

Comment: No its not a bug. Looking at the tracer again, I can see you use multicast and that is your bug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like an end user issue.

> ```
> 2013-09-04,21:11:55.625,MacBook-local >>> (processProduct-route) log[SELECT,${header.CamelSqlQuery},${header.CamelSqlRowCount}] --> multicast <<< Pattern:InOnly, Headers:{breadcrumbId=MacBook-local}, BodyType:org.springframework.util.LinkedCaseInsensitiveMap, Body:{product_id=273}
> ```

The details from the trace logging indicates a multicast EIP is in use (see above). And when you do that then the multicast copied the incoming message (original message), and each receiver gets a copy of that "original" message. So that would explain why these headers is not there, as the original copy does not have the SQL update headers.

So remove the multicast and just use a straight pipeline.

You can read about multicast and pipeline here

- http://camel.apache.org/multicast.html
- http://camel.apache.org/pipes-and-filters.html

Comment: after taking the multi-cast out ${headers.CamelSqlUpdateCount} now reflect the amount of rows inserted however ${headers.CamelSqlQuery} still doesn't produce anything. Am I misunderstanding something again?

Comment: Read the web site about CamelSqlQuery what it does. Its for overriding the endpoint query to run another query. This header is optional, and if not provided the endpoint query is used.